# Change "unambiguous" auto import of android.util.Log in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a custom logging class which is also called `Log` and has the static methods `v()`, `e()` and so on.

Now when I'm typing `Log.e(` the auto import will import `android.util.Log` on the fly. An option is to disable `Add unambiguous imports on the fly` but then it'll not import anything.

So can the automatic import be changed to always import my `Log` class?

Comment: You can just wait until the lint show the unknown class, press `alt + enter` combination and then select the right class you want to import

Comment: That's what I'm using at the moment, but it's annoying

Comment: Just a thought: people reading your code familiar with android but not your code will assume that `Log` means the "standard" `android.util.Log`, rather than your custom class. It's a bit like calling a class `List` or `String` - confusion abounds. You should maybe consider naming it differently.

Comment: @MariusBoepple you should accept an answer because it could be helpfull for other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Android Studio settings, go to

```
Editor > General > Auto Imports
```

In the section named *Exclude from Import and Completion* add `android.util.Log`.

After that, when you start typing `Log` the suggestions will start with your custom class.

---

**EDIT:** don't forget to set it to Project. So for other projects it won't be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to start typing the class name, Like

```
Log.d
```

Then when the suggestion import popup appears, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and another side popup will appear with fast exclusion rules based on package depth like in the image below.

[image: fast esclusions]

Then if you want rollback the exclusion or change the scope (IDE/Project) you can go in the *Auto Import* panel and change accordingly per your needs like in the image below:

[image]

Tested on AS 3.0 Beta 7